# Why is this Jquery Login Code Misbehaving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, authentication, phonegap

I created a login API I want to use in an app, I'm testing it on a PC browser,
it validates the login credentials correctly but instead of redirecting to specified
page,it just displays the success message.

Here is my jquery code that is supposed to handle the login:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#login").click(function(e) {
      $("#result").hide();
       e.preventDefault();
        var luser = $("#username").val();
        var lpass = $("#password").val();
        $.post("https://example.com/app/login-api.php", {luser:luser, lpass:lpass}, function(data) {
        $("#result").show();
        if(data == "successok") {
                window.localStorage.setItem("username","luser");
                window.location.href = "index2.html";
            }
            else
            {
            $("#result").html(data);    
            }

        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

The login API echoes "successok" on correct input but an error message otherwise.
According to the code above, I expect a redirection to index2.html, but what I get is "successok" being displayed on the result div.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Hello. Can you share your login-api.php response code please ?

Comment: May be its have some unwanted space.Try this  `if(data.trim() == "successok")`

Comment: Yes,thanks. It was unwanted space.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What data are you expecting to return by your ajax request? is it xml, json, script, text, 
 or html? maybe you could try this?

```
$.post("https://example.com/app/login-api.php", {luser:luser, lpass:lpass}, 
function(data) {
            $("#result").show();
            if(data.trim() == "successok") {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("username","luser");
                    window.location.href = "index2.html";
                }
                else
                {
                $("#result").html(data);    
                }

            });
            return false;
      },'text');
```

Comment: Just FYI, it's for reasons like this that sending AJAX responses as plain text is a bad idea. Use a serialised format such as XML or JSON instead, that way it's impossible for this to happen